# File names from two relative paths using regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, relative-path, filepath

I would like to find fileName with extension in the text using regular expression(s). I have text like this:

```
<p>Some text<a href="/relativePath1/file.ext">link</a>.<p>SomeText<img 
src="/relativePath2/file2.ext" style="width: 200.2px; height: 1141px;"></p>
```

I know that two relative paths, and I want to extract **file names**, that are situated in this relative path directory. I don't want files from another relative or absolute paths. There can be more occurences of these paths. Extensions may vary.

I have tried this `[\w-]+\.\w+`, but it collides with style - width property, and it finds also file names from another relative paths in the text. Thanks for you help, in advance.

Additional clarification:
I want to find file names that lies in that two **relative paths**. I know paths, but I dont know which files are there. There can be multiple occurences.

Comment: ok, you have several relative paths, and you just want to match certain file names from certain paths, right ? So which paths are you talking about ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it:

```
 '/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z]{3,4}$/'
```

Or maybe use [`basename()`](https://www.php.net/basename)

Comment: Well that's a common mistake, extensions are not limited to only characters and they are certainly not limited to 3 or 4 characters. For example this is a valid name `my.tar.gz`. Adding `^$` makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 0):

The input is HTML so I would suggest a DOM solution:

```
$html = <<<EOF
<p>Some text<a href="/relativePath1/file.ext">link</a>.<p>SomeText<img
src="/relativePath2/file2.ext" style="width: 200.2px; height: 1141px;"></p>
EOF;

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($html);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

// select all src and href attributes
foreach($selector->query('//@href | //@src') as $url) {
    // extract the filename from path using basename()
    var_dump(basename($url->nodeValue));
}
```

Output:

```
string(8) "file.ext"
string(9) "file2.ext"
```